# SendMessage как работает

Tags: c++, winapi

Я использую `WM_CTLCOLOREDIT`
Кнопка отлавливает и меняет цвет текста, как сделать так чтобы я мог управлять какой цветом текста. У меня есть на все это условие, не могу понять одно как правильно использовать функцию `SendMessage(hwnd,WM_CTLCOLOREDIT,???,???`)

Что прописывать вместо вопросов

Answer (score 2):

`WM_CTLCOLOREDIT` - это уведомление. Оно играет пассивную роль, по типу calback'а. Поэтому управлять цветом через это сообщение можно только перехватывая его в родительской процедуре окна. Вызывать его напрямую бесполезно.

А вот, чтобы спровоцировать его генерацию, достаточно просто перерисовать контрол: `InvalidateRect(hwndCtl, nullptr, TRUE);`